# How to work out the cumulative compound interest of something over a set period?

Tags: finance

For example:
If I want to get to a total of 1,500 in 30 increments. Each time the base value increases by 5%.

For example

| Increment | Value | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 10.5 | 20.5 |
| 3 | 11.025 | 31.525 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 30 | ... | 1500 |

How do I work out what the initial value is to get a total of 1500 after 30 5% increases (compounding)?

Comment: Do you know the formula for compound interest?

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate I wasn't too clear. It's compound interest, but I'm struggling to work out the total. So not the amount I have on week 30, but how much I have if I added up day 1 + day 2 + day 3 etc. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. Think about what happens in that total column. What's 20.5? It's actually $10+10*1.05$, then that $31.525$ is actually $10+10*1.05+10*1.05^2$. So, if you sum up that total column all the way, you'll end up with $10$ being included in all 30 rows, $10*1.05$ 29 times, $10*1.05^2$ 28 times, etc. So, you overall total is $10*30+10*1.05*29+10*1.05^2*28+...+10*1.05^{29}$. Set that equal to $1500$, replace the $10$ with a variable (since that was meant to be your principal), and you've got your formula.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you are adding an extra amount each time on top of the compound interest.  I assume not in what follows

Hints:

- Each increment involves multiplying by $1.05$
- $30$ increments involves multiplying $30$ times by $1.05$, i.e. by $1.05^{30}$.  How much is this?
- What number do you need to multiply by $1.05^{30}$ to get $1500$?

If you are adding an extra amount $x$ each time then you need to adjust this, with what amounts to a geometric series

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate I wasn't too clear. It's compound interest, but I'm struggling to work out the total. So not the amount I have on week 30, but how much I have if I added up day 1 + day 2 + day 3 etc. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @TobyCannon Not really: the point about *compound* interest is that you multiply at each stage rather than add

Comment: So it would compound at each stage. I'm trying to find out what the initial value would be if I want to add up all values in the series and the final total value to be 1500

Comment: @TobyCannon That suggests you are adding an extra amount $x$ each time.  Does the initial amount get $30$ doses of compound interest and the last $x$ only $1$ dose? If so, you get $1.05^{30}x + 1.05^{29}x + \cdots + 1.05^{1}x = 1500$ and you need to use the geometric series.